# How to group Nodes by Nodegroup

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I am attempting to query the total number of Nodes in a Kubernetes cluster, grouped by the nodegroup_name.
Is there a promql to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, in promql, is as follows

`sum by (nodegroup_name) (kubelet_node_name)`